How to change dynamically between styles stored in style.xml for Flutter Mobile Application
This is my styles.xml file:
<resources>
<!--  Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off  -->
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
<!--  Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame  -->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>
<!--  Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding.  -->
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
<item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
</resources>

How can I change between them while running the app? "Launch Theme" is just for initializing the app and the "NormalTheme" for the rest.
I found something called toggleTheme() but it didn't work for me

You want to switch between themes like light mode and dark mode?
If yes, go for this:
theme_config.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clock/utils/my_colors.dart';

ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
    indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: MyColors.lightRed, width: 4.0),
    ),
    labelColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
    unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade400, fontSize: 10),
    dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12, letterSpacing: 1.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  ),
  primaryColor: const Color(0xFFfafafa),
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.white,
  floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2b2119),
  ),
);

ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: MyColors.lightRed, width: 4.0),
      ),
      labelColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
      unselectedLabelStyle:
          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 10),
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
      labelStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12, letterSpacing: 1.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor,
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    primaryColor: Colors.amber);


  ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: MyColors.lightRed, width: 4.0),
          ),
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
          unselectedLabelStyle:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 10),
          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12, letterSpacing: 1.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        primaryColor: Colors.amber);


  

ThemeData halloweenTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple, width: 4.0),
          ),
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
          unselectedLabelStyle:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 10),
          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12, letterSpacing: 1.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.backgroundColor,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        primaryColor: Colors.amber);

Then, in the main file, add this:
main.dart:
import 'theme_config.dart';




class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: darkTheme.
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

Or
If you want only a light or dark theme, call this method:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

Note:
I used MyColors. sometimes, you sould use Colors.
